# User order views does not display orders for user despite permission

Tags: 7, commerce

The user order views' access permission is "View own orders of any type". I have given this permission to authenticated users yet the user sees only this message "You have not placed any orders with us yet.". What am I missing?

Comment: have you completed any orders i.e did whole checkout flow?

Comment: Yes. User one can see the orders on the user's profile but the user can't see it.

Comment: Have you set `Create orders of any type` for authenticated user? Also can you upload a screenshot of confirmation page on a purchase by authenticated user?

Comment: "Create orders of any type" is set. Interesting enough after an order, a user can view the order just placed by using the link on the order complete page but can't view all orders from the user profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've most likely edited the View to include a new relationship - perhaps from line items to products - that adds an access check to the View's results that the user doesn't pass. If this is the case, open your View's "Advanced" fieldset, edit the "Query settings", and check the box to "Disable SQL rewriting".

Comment: Thank you for your response. I haven't edited the view. So far I have only opened it to view the permission setting.